# A ML classifier for predicting the hourly direction for a group of stocks where training stocks don't match out of sample stocks

Tags: time-series, supervised-learning, autoencoders

I have historical data for 100 stocks (call them A). I would like to train a model jointly on all stocks which will learn from the cross sectional historical activity, to predict another set of stocks (B), where the the intersection is only partial (some stocks get delisted, some are added etc.)

Is there a way to do this? I would prefer to utilise unsupervised learning along the way to find features which may be subtle and non obvious.

The target variable for a given stock is -1/1 for one period ahead.